# this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"))); exception on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, exception

Everything was working fine and after I did some more coding (edited some strings not affecting this form), the app wouldn't start and started to throw an exception on:

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"))); exception
```

When the icon was removed from the form, new exception emerged at:

```
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

This form isn't even the initial startup form.
I have no idea what happened, is it possible I pressed some hotkey and messed something up?

Also;

```
        public PDFSettings()
        {

        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("Repeating");

        }
```

When the app is started, this message box keeps looping, like the form keeps reinitializing, after clicking OK on the message box, it just reopens.

Comment: Show the git difference of your edits, it should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what exception was thrown? Use Visual Studio's "copy exception" option to copy the full exception details to the clipboard, and paste them into your question.

Comment: Sorry, here it is: System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Message=Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

Comment: Could you give more code? The current information is difficult to help you solve the problem.